# Disapperead All Products and Error on System.log

Tags: product, magento2.4

congratulations to the community, I use it a lot to find solutions that are always useful, but this time I'm completely blocked.

After doing a `setup: upgrade` and a `setup: di: compile` following installation of Welt Pixels, all products in the categories are gone.
I can see them in the Products section (in the backend) but in the Frontend they seem "invisible". In the categories it doesn't tell me that there are no products, they just aren't seen.

I've tried re-indexing, clearing cache, and all ordinary operations, but nothing to do.

I tried to see the log files (system.log) which gives me this error:

```
main.CRITICAL: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml on line 27 [] []
```

In the phtml file mentioned in the logs I find this:

```
<span class="product-image-container product-image-container-<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getProductId() ?>">
    <span class="product-image-wrapper">
        <img class="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getClass()) ?>"
            <?php foreach ($block->getCustomAttributes() as $name => $value): ?>
                <?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($name) ?>="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($value) ?>" 
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            src="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getImageUrl()) ?>"
            loading="lazy"
            <?php if ($borders || $enableLazyLoadingWithoutBorders): ?>
                width="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getWidth()) ?>"
                height="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getHeight()) ?>"
            <?php else: ?>
                max-width="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getWidth()) ?>"
                max-height="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getHeight()) ?>"
            <?php endif; ?>
            alt="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getLabel()) ?>"/></span>
</span>
```

Specifically, line 27 reads:

```
<?php foreach ($block->getCustomAttributes() as $name => $value): ?>
```

I am hoping for your guidance, I can't figure out if it's an array problem or something.

Comment: have you used any custom extensions?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I have one Extension enabled "LiteExtensione migration from Woocommerce", but i have put them few days ago (i have already done a setup:upgrade before, and i haven't had problem). Today i've try to install Welt Pixels free with composer for the slider, and the installation was good. But after setup:upgrade i've seen the error

Comment: Try to disabled that Welt Pixels extension and then try.

Comment: @Alberto i have same issue facing , which changes throgh you have fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, so I removed the lines below and started to display the products.
I don't know if this will affect other features.

`<?php foreach ($block->getCustomAttributes() as $name => $value): ?>` 
`<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($name) ?>="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($value) ?>"`
`<?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: Hii this one works but might break the functionality for future, have you come up with why this issue happens or any alternate solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the similar issue while upgrade 2.3.6 to 2.4.3 and while debugging, i found `$block->getCustomAttributes()` returning empty string and hence `<?php foreach ($block->getCustomAttributes() as $name => $value): ?>` statement throws exception saying invalid argument supplied to `foreach()`.

I am not sure about the root cause of this but i did the following workaround to avoid any future conflicts with functionality.

```
<?php if (!empty($block->getCustomAttributes())): ?>
        <?php foreach ($block->getCustomAttributes() as $name => $value): ?>
            <?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($name) ?>="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml($value) ?>"
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```